# Resistor connected to the non-inverting pin of a follower op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I went through [this schematic](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/str-30-60v-bldc-mdk-gevb_schematic.pdf.pdf).

At the bottom they are using a follower op-amp with a resistor (R3, R5, R8 and R9, 10 kΩ) connected to the non-inverting input:

[image]

I was wondering why, to me they add nothing.

Comment: Read the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncs2006-d.pdf), p.13.

Answer (score 1):

The [data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncs2006-d.pdf) indicates that inputs are sensitive to over-voltage. They have several techniques to prevent this on page 13.

The resistors are chosen so that the input current does not exceed a maximum rating for the maximum expected transient voltages.

[image]

Comment: Oh that's it then

Answer (score 0):

In case of spikes on the input (for example, due to stray capacitance across R15, the divider from the phase voltage) the input 10k resistors will limit the current into the op-amp input protection networks. Probably not so useful on the bus voltage measurement.

The [NCS20062](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncs2006-d.pdf) is rated to withstand 10mA so that would allow a spike of up to about 100V.